# If $H \unlhd G$ is CC-closed, then $H$ is a Hall subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I'm stuck with this problem.

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of a finite group $G$ such that $C_G(x)\subseteq H$ for every non-identity element $x\in H$ (that is, $H$ is a normal CC-subgroup of $G$). 
Then $\textrm{gcd}(|H|,|G/H|)=1$ (i.e. $H$ is a Hall-subgroup of $G$).

I think that Sylow's Theorems would be helpful here. 
I spent hours thinking and I couldn't solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to help people search: "Why is the Frobenius kernel a Hall subgroup?"

Comment: And here is a generalization of the statement, with more or less the same proof: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76413

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider a *p*-element of *H* and an element of the center of a Sylow *p*-subgroup containing it.  Centers and centralizers unite!

> If *p* divides *H*, then let *Q* be a Sylow *p*-subgroup of *H*, and let *P* be a Sylow *p*-subgroup of *G* containing *Q*.  Let *z* be an element of the center of *P*, and let *x* be a non-identity element of *Q*.  Since *x* and *z* commute, $z \in C_G(x) \leq H$, and so *z* in *H*.  However, *z* is in the center of *P*, and so $P \leq C_G(z) \leq H$ and *P* is actually a Sylow *p*-subgroup of *H* as well.  Hence $[G:H]$ is not divisible by *p*.