# Problem 1D.2 from Martin Isaacs's Finite Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I try to solve the following problem:

> Fix a prime $p$, and suppose that a subgroup $H \subset G$ (of a
> finite group $G$) has the property that $C_G(x) \subset H$ for every
> element $x \in H$ having order $p$ ($C_G(x)$ is the centralizer
> of $x$ in $G$). Show that $p$ cannot divide both $|H|$ and $|G:H|$.

My attempt is the following.

Assume $p \mid |H|$.
Then, by Cauchy's theorem, there exists an element $x \in H$ of order $p$.
Let $O$ be the conjugacy class in $G$ containing $x$.
Then $|O| = |G:C_G(x)|$.
By assumption, $C_G(x) \subset H$, hence $|G:C_G(x)| =|G:H||H:C_G(x)|$.
Assume moreover that $p \mid |G:H|$.
Then we have that $p |O|$....

I wanted to deduce a contradiction.

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I solved the problem, using a similar argument in the answer of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76413/g-finite-group-h-leq-g-such-that-c-gx-subseteq-h-quad-forall-x-in-h-suc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a somewhat different solution (making use of actions of groups) than the one you are referring to of Arturo Magidin. Any reference below is to the book of M. Isaacs, *Finite Group Theor*y.

Assume the prime $p$ divides $|H|$. Then a $P \in Syl_p(H)$ exists, with $P$ non-trivial. We will show that in fact $P \in Syl_p(G)$, implying $p \nmid |G:H|$.

Put the set $\Omega=\{\text {elements of order $p$ in $P$} \}$. By Problem $(1A.8)(b)$ $|\Omega| \equiv -1$ mod $p$. Let $N_G(P)$ act by conjugation on $\Omega$ and let $x_1, \ldots, x_k$ be the representatives of the different orbits under this action. Then
$$|\Omega|=\sum_{i=1}^k|N_G(P):C_{N_G(P)}(x_i)|$$
Since for each $i$, $x_i \in H$, and using the premiss, we have
$$C_{N_G(P)}(x_i)=C_G(x_i) \cap N_G(P) \subseteq H \cap N_G(P)=N_H(P) \subseteq N_G(P).$$
This means that $|N_G(P):N_H(P)|$ divides $|N_G(P):C_{N_G(P)}(x_i)|$ for each $i$, hence, using the sum above, $|N_G(P):N_H(P)| \mid |\Omega|$. In particular, since $|\Omega| \equiv -1$ mod $p$, $p \nmid |N_G(P):N_H(P)|$. In addition, because $P$ is Sylow in $H$, $\ p \nmid |N_H(P):P|$. So, $p$ does not divide $|N_G(P):P|=|N_G(P):N_H(P)| \cdot |N_H(P):P|$. Now we can apply Problem $(1A.10)$: $|G:P| \equiv |N_G(P):P|$ mod $p$, so $p$ does not divide $|G:P|$, whence $P$ is Sylow in $G$, as wanted. $\square$